# Обновление GUI в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

Здравствуйте. Нужно в углу отрисовывать собранные бонусы.
Конечно, самое простое:

```
void OnGUI()
{
        GUI.Box(new Rect(5,5, 100, 100), "Vitamin counter: " + BonusBehaviour.getVitaminCounter(), vitaminCounterStyle);
}
```

Но получается, что GUI каждый раз лезет получить очки и добавляет их. Хотелось бы отрисовывать только, когда они изменились. То есть:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if(vitaminCounterChanged)
    {
        int left = Screen.width / 2;
        int top = Screen.height / 2;
        GUI.Box(new Rect(5,5, 100, 100), "Vitamin counter: " + BonusBehaviour.getVitaminCounter(), vitaminCounterStyle);
        vitaminCounterChanged = false;
    }
}
```

Есть переменная vitaminCounterChanged, которая true, когда предмет подобран. Но тогда GUI вообще не появляется. Вернее появляется наверно на один кадр.
Нужно, чтоб старый GUI не стирался что ли, пока я не укажу.
В общем обновлять по событию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я правильно понимаю, что BonusBehaviour.getVitaminCounter() и vitaminCounterStyle возвращают номер объекта и его стиль соответственно?

И да, у нас на лекциях графики был хороший пример с ключами, простой, но наглядный, могу отправить. И да, у тебя слишком много разных бонусов? Ты не можешь отрисовать, к примеру, какую-то серую неактивную область для каждого бонуса, который ты еще не получил и проверять, не получил ли ты новый. Тогда можно будет менять цвет в GUI-шке, и это будет намного проще, нет? Или тебе нужно что-то другое? Объясни попродробнее, тогда смогу помочь чем-то, если еще требуется

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать `event` на изменение значение счетчика и по нему менять локальное значение переменной в классе с методом `OnGUI()`
Например

```
public class Counter {
    public static event OnCountChanged = delegate { };
    private int count = 0;
    public int Count {
        get {
            return count;
        }
        set {
            count = value;
            OnCountChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

И в классе gui

```
public class CounterGui : MonoBehaviour {
    private int lastCounterValue = 0;
    void Awake() {
        //подписка на событие
        Counter.OnCountChanged += OnCounterChange;
    }

    void OnDestroy() {
        //отписка от события при уничтожении объекта
        Counter.OnCountChanged -= OnCounterChange;
    }

    void OnCounterChange() {
        lastCounterValue = Counter.Count;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        // отобразить lastCounterValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я вообще вывожу с помощью добавления на канвас Text, потом в коде даю ссылку на него и создаю метод UpdateLocalUI() в котором приравниваю необходимые данные тексту вот так:

```
strenghtScore.text = ((int)StrengthPlayer).ToString(); // Прочность планеты игрока
```